# How to avoid duplicate elements in Android ArrayObjectAdapter

Tags: android, collections, duplicates, android-arrayadapter, linkedhashset

I'm adding elements to an `Android (Kotlin)` adapter extending `ArrayObjectAdapter`.
I use addAll to add items.

From ArrayObjectAdapter:

```
public void addAll(int index, Collection items) {
    int itemsCount = items.size();
    if (itemsCount == 0) {
        return;
    }
    mItems.addAll(index, items);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(index, itemsCount);
}
```

My question is, how do I avoid duplicate elements in the adapter. The problem is, backing data collection for `ArrayObjectAdapter` is a List (not a Set) and when I use `addAll` it is possible to add a duplicate element. I can use `addAll` with the `LinkedHashSet` (as it takes a Collection as an input) but if I add another `hashset` it might have duplicates with the 1st `hashset` so I still need to check the whole list. I can of course go through all the list elements every time I add something but this is not a good solution for obvious reasons. Is there an efficient way to prevent duplicates in this scenario? Thanks.

Comment: You can filter out the duplicate items based on some id or unique parameter. Or as given in the answer you can use DiffUtils which helps you to find out the difference between two collections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DiffUtil` in your Adapter.

This is documents about that [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil).

> DiffUtil is a utility class that can calculate the difference between
>   two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the
>   first list into the second one.
>
> It can be used to calculate updates for a RecyclerView Adapter. See
>   ListAdapter and AsyncListDiffer which can compute diffs using DiffUtil
>   on a background thread.

This is a sample of DiffUtil:

```
class ArticleListDiffTool(internal var oldList: List<Product>, internal var newList: List<Product>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

    private val TAG = "ArticleListDiffTool"

    override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
        return oldList.size
    }

    override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
        return newList.size
    }

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].id === newList[newItemPosition].id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return oldList[oldItemPosition].id === newList[newItemPosition].id
    }


}
```

You only have to pass your old and new list.

Hope This helped.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this helps me. Here is an example of what I'm trying to solve. I have a list of 10 elements, then I add another 20 elements. One of these 20 elements matches one of the elements in the 1st 10. Is there an efficient way to detect this situation and remove the duplicate? Note that I don't have direct access to the list (it is a private member of the ArrayObjectAdapter).

Comment: your 1st 10 element is your old list and your new list is 1andother 20 elements.
You have to pass them into your DiffUtil and it handles repeated items in your list.
As described  here :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil
And this class is optimized too, Then don't worry about it's performance
``` It has O(N + D^2) expected time performance where D is the length of the edit script```

Comment: DiffUtil does not prevent duplicate item which is a common misconception, instead it is used to easily perform update on items that has been changed, removed, or added. E.g. if you have A,B,C as initial item in adapter and you submit ACD it will remove B in the list and add D while also updating A and C if there is any changes based on `areItemsTheSame` and `areContentsTheSame`. If you submit a list in a `ListAdapter` that contains two identical such as AABC item it will show as is.